# how to connect a html form with different php file

Tags: php, html

i am new to php. i have designed a form in html and its php part in different file.now i want   to connect the file with each other. i have tried using

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
```

but connecting in this way is not secured and i cannot connect  using

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
```

as this will work only if the php codes and html codes are written in same file. please help   me.

if i use

and if someone enters this url as

```
http://www.variable.com/file.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

then it will show alert box telling it is hacked.

Comment: What does this mean: `but connecting in this way is not secured` ?

Comment: `is not secured`? and what do you think is secured?

Comment: I really don't understand what you really want.

Comment: what is the problem with first one?

Comment: `<form action="otherphpfile.php">`? It's not rocket science... If you want "secured", then `action="https://example.com/otherphpfile.php"`, though your form should've been loaded from an https url to begin with.

Comment: @MarcB don't forget for `method` attribute :)

Comment: Just add the PHP code in the same HTML document and it will work.

Comment: @SakhalTurkaystan `as this will work only if the php codes and html codes are written in same file.`. He knows that.

Comment: @Mr. Smith Then why is he asking if he can make it work?

Comment: We know he does not want it in the same file but we do not know what he needs then.

Comment: if i use <form action="file.php" method="post"> and is someone enters this url as http://www.variable.com/test_form.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E then it show alert box.

Answer (score 0):

As the Method is 'POST', it's Secure. No need to worry.

Or else..

Create a 'Session' on submiting the form. So no direct access to the php file would occur.

Thanks.

- bhumin.vadalia@gmail.com

Comment: `As the Method is 'POST', it's Secure. No need to worry.` It is very bold statement.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand you well, but connecting it this way is secure. If you have this form in html file:

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">

      <input type="password" name="password">

</form>
```

And you have file called file.php in the same directory it is perfectly fine. In the PHP file you should have:

```
<?php

$password = $_POST["password"];
```

To get your input. Ask me something else if you don't understand it :)

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your comments, your field shows raw text without "escaping" HTML characters.

In your **file.php** put or edit with:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['yourfield']);
```

Then output will not be "hacked" by JavaScript.

Comment: thnx..let me try it out